# Using "es" to link a clause with infinitive

Tags: pronoun, infinitive

There are some German sentences with an infinitive clause that are used without a linking word. And there are other cases where a pronoun is used to link the infinitive clause to the main clause, e.g. (from [here](https://www.busuu.com/dashboard#/learning/course/start/objective_de_20131106_55/4_2_11_N_copy2/activity_entity_4_2_11_N/exercise_2)):

> Diese Webseite ermöglicht **es** dir, Sprachen kostenlos zu lernen.

Why do we need to add **"es"** here? Can we skip it here? What is the rule?

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/63077/35111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [linked question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/63077/35111) given above mostly answers the question, especially the accepted answer. But I had some additional thoughts that might be useful. I don't know if this will all be strictly correct, but it's what I've gleaned from what I've heard in conversational German. Keep in mind that formal German (for example a newscast or scholarly article) is not the same as conversational German. In conversational language, people tend to go by what "sounds" right rather than keeping track of a list of rules.

There seems to be no strict cutoff for when to use placeholder or not. If it's a simple combination, e.g. *Ich lerne Deutsch zu sprechen,* you don't need the *es* or even a comma. More complex sentences would be more likely to use an *es*. A lot depends on if the main clause would seem ungrammatical without the *es*. For example in *Es ist möglich, kostenlos Sprachen zu lernen,* the *es* is the subject and it would be hard to repair the damage if it was dropped. It depends too on where the *es* would go in the main clause; if it would be last then it's probably unnecessary.

Note that other placeholders are possible depending on circumstances: *Ich dachte daran, eine Sprache kostenlos zu lernen.* Here, the *dar-* part of *daran* is the placeholder.