# "Er schaffte es, die Papiere fristgerecht abzuschicken"-without "es"

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence:

> Er schaffte es, die Papiere fristgerecht abzuschicken.

Is it possible to omit "es" here? If not, then could someone please pinpoint the exact rule that governs such structures?

Comment: "Er schaffte die fristgerechte Papierabschickung" ist theoretisch möglich, aber nicht zu empfehlen

Comment: @npst Er schaffte das fristgerechte Abschicken der Papiere

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/q/63077/35111.

Answer (score 2):

Let us first analyze how this structure works and maybe your question will be answered by then. You will get an answer anyway.

The base of all this is an idiomatic phrase:

> schaffen +*Nomen* in *Akkusativ*.

Which means *to achieve sth. / to manage to get sth done* or the like. For instance:

> Er schaffte die Prüfung.
> <sub>He passed the test (examination).</sub>

Note, that "schaffen" in this meaning needs a *Nomen* (noun) or something that can act like a *Nomen* - a *Nominalphrase*.

The problem is, we do not always have a *Nominalphrase*, like when we want to say "*he managed to walk*". We could, in a pinch, of course create a *Nomen* e.g. by replacing the verb "to walk" with the noun "the walk":

> He achieved a walk.
> <sub>Er schaffte einen Gang.</sub>

This is how these (suggested in commentaries)

> Er schaffte die fristgerechte Papierabschickung.
> Er schaffte das fristgerechte Abschicken der Papiere.

work. "Die fristgerechte Papierabschickung" and "das fristgerechte Abschicken der Papiere" are both *Nominalphrasen*.

But this is replacing an *action* ("to walk") with a thing ("the walk") and if we want something genuine German has a joker: "es"!

This "es" is called a *Korrelat* and works like a placeholder for something to be filled later. Like saying "let me make this point clear" and then proceed to indeed make clear what "this point" in detail is. And, best of all, "es" is a *Pronomen* (pronoun) and hence can act on behalf of a *Nomen*.

So, we have:

> Er schaffte es.

This is already the complete sentence. What comes after, the

> die Papiere fristgerecht abzuschicken

is just the explanation, what "es" stands for. It is an action. And this is why you need the joker. Consider the following:

> Er schaffte Gehen.

here we have not "gehen" the *Verb* but "das Gehen", the *Verb* made *Nomen*. We could even enter the article:

> Er schaffte das Gehen (aber nicht das Laufen).

Whereas when we want to use the *Verb* we need the Joker - the "es" - and put the *Verb* in *Infinitiv*:

> Er schaffte es zu gehen.

Answer (score 2):

The critera for when "es" can be used like this (as a Korrelat) are not well explained even in Duden grammar. Duden simply shows observations of a few example verbs. So I suppose that there is no clear cut rules for when to use it (for non-linguists at least), other than learning about it on a verb-by-verb basis.

Of course, as another user answers, the information structure is relevant too. But it does not explain it all.

I would put "schaffen" into the "varying" category - possible with or without.

In comparison, two examples: "vermuten" is never used with *es*, and "etw. für etw. halten" is always used with *es*. (As long as *es* is used as a placeholder like here)